# How to get 2d array from a string (whole sentence) (each word a separate row)?

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I've got some homework for my university subject, this is just a one part of the code that I don't know what is the most efficient way that I could use in the future and also to understand it fully.

I am new to programming so I still do not have that logic with things like this, one thing that is helping my is white board on which I "test" program to see what happens, it helped me for some things.
(This is my first post, not sure if it is writed the right way)

I tried to make it with nested loop, with the if condition whenever it finds blank space, it starts with new row and continue to read from string. Not sure if I've done it right but I'd like to see how would you do it so.

I can write my code here but everything is named in my language, this is part of that function:

brojac = counter

br_beline = blank space

pamcenje = variable to continue from where J lasted in i = 0; so when i = 1, j starts from last for it has been

rnk = char array, the string from input

novi = 2d array that I want to make it

```
int orf(char rnk[]) {
   int i,j;
   int brojac = 0;
   int pamcenje = 0;
   char novi[MAKS][MAKS] = {}; //MAKS IS 100
   int br_beline = brojac_belina(rnk);
   for (i = 0; i <= br_beline; ++i, brojac = 0){
        for (j = pamcenje; brojac < 1; ++j, ++pamcenje){
             if (rnk[j] != ' ' & rnk[j] != NULL) {
                  novi[i][j] = rnk[j];
                  pamcenje = j;
              }
              else{
                 ++brojac;
                 pamcenje = j;
              }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtok()` is, as others have written, probably the solution.

Here's another that is pretty trivial, if you want to work with every byte in your code.

```
#define MAKS 100
void orf( char rnk[] ) {
    char novi[MAKS][MAKS];

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while( rnk[k] ) {
        while( rnk[k] && rnk[k] == ' ' ) k++;
        while( rnk[k] && rnk[k] != ' ' ) novi[ i ][ j++ ] = rnk[ k++ ];
        novi[ i++ ][ j ] = '\0';
        j = 0;
    }
    for( int x = 0; x < i; x++ )
        puts( &novi[ x ][ 0 ] );
}

int main() {
    orf( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" );
    return 0;
}
```

```
The
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
```

It's good to learn. And, sometimes, just using 'generic' variable names may help others to understand the code much more easily.